# How to write one line If statement using Handlebars?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, handlebars.js

I would like to know what is the correct syntax of this:

```
<li class="nav-item {{# if undefined !== user}} hidden {{/if}}">
```

I want to add class name **hidden** if user variable exists.

It displays an error:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't use `undefined !== user` expression, it's not valid syntax. The `if` block helper will check for undefined, so there is no need for `undefined !== user`, just use: `{{#if user}}`

```
<li class="nav-item {{#if user}}non-empty{{/if}}">
```

If you want to check if `user` is empty you should use the `unless` helper

```
<li class="nav-item {{#unless user}}empty-user{{/unless}}">
```

Here's is the [code](https://github.com/wycats/handlebars.js/blob/7535e48a7969229f44489124a8ef07bd17363f06/lib/handlebars/helpers/if.js) for the default `if` helper, basically it will evaluate to true if non falsy value is passed.

Comment: Thanks. One more question: is it possible to write something similar {{if # !user}} without writing own helpers?

Comment: Yes, use `unless` helper.